# JSF + Spring Data JPA + Maven using Eclipse

Tags: maven, jsf, jpa

I want to learn how to create maven project which handles Spring Data JPA and JSF. I tried to find a lot for simple examples but I could not. Can anybody please help me out? I am using Eclipse as a development platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are technologies in opposite ends of the stack.

Learn basics of Spring Data from [Petri](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-one-configuration/)

Learn basics of JSF here by [MKYong](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jsf-2-0-tutorials/)

Both use maven.

For additional JSF resources, use for instance [this](https://jsf.zeef.com/bauke.scholtz) as offset.